# How to handle several hundred/thousand connections with a single server?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, server

I'm writing a server in C# but i have encountered a problem.

The dataflow itself wont be that big but the number of connections is, and the problem is any of these connections can send data at any time and obviously i dont want to have several thousand different threads listening for data on every socket.

So how can i handle this?

In short how can i listen for data from multiple sockets without adding more threads?

Comment: A little more detail might be helpful. Especially when considering alternatives. Are you saying that several hundred thousand clients will be simultaneously connecting to this server? Are we talking about connections to a database server or just a web server? If the former, can the clients only connect when they need to send/receive data? If the latter, won't that happen automagically?

Comment: This question is too broad and even a little off topic, there is no clear question with a direct unique answer.

Comment: "Are you saying that several hundred thousand clients will be simultaneously connecting to this server?"
Yes.

Comment: what not use IIS (simple rest services) the mountain you are about to climb has been conquered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use async programming.

This means setting a socket into listen and doing socket.beginaccept, etc. THis will post the incoming tcp work onto a thread from the io thread pool

The newer c# 5 async await stuff raises the abstraction level but its still basically the same under the hood. But it does make it easier to write 'straight ahead' code in async mode as opposed to the beginxxx model which requires you to convert you server code base into an event driven one